# What needs to be done?

Tags: wo2007061430a1

In reference to the patent: [WO2007061430A1](https://www.google.com/patents/WO2007061430A1)

This was filed way back in 2006. I am one of the co-inventor of this patent application. The event code seems to be '121' - what does this exactly mean? What do I need to do here?

Thanks,
Sujeet

Answer (score 1):

The document is an international ("PCT") application filed in 2006;

It also claims priority to U.S. application serial number 11/284,659, which does not appear to have ever been published as an application or granted.

Based on this page, the application was positively denied entry into the EPO and German patent offices:
https://worldwide.espacenet.com/publicationDetails/inpadoc?CC=WO&NR=2007061430A1&KC=A1&FT=D&ND=3&date=20070531&DB=&locale=en_EP

Most countries have a time limit of ~30 months to transition from an international application into a national application. Therefore, no other national-stage applications are possible based off this PCT.

There is a small chance that U.S. application ser. no. 11/284,659 is still pending rather than abandoned (because it was never published, its status is unknown to the public).

Answer (score -2):

> Date: Aug 29, 2007
>   Code: 121
>   Event: Ep: the epo has been informed by wipo that ep was designated in this application

Comment: Some commentary and explanation are required to make this answer adequate.